# Single query: Bind Variables vs Literals

Tags: oracle, bind

I am executing only one query. Which of the two queries, given below, would take more time to execute?

```
SELECT COLUMN2 FROM SOMETABLE WHERE COLUMN1 = 'Some Value'
```

and

```
DECLARE
  VAR1 VARCHAR2;
  VAR2 VARCHAR2;
BEGIN
  VAR2 := 'Some Value';
  SELECT COLUMN2 INTO VAR2 FROM SOMETABLE WHERE COLUMN1 = :VAR1
END;
```

Comment: Fist of all it depends what you want to do with the result. According to me the second query will take more time, because there will be a context switch between PL/SQL and SQL. By more time I mean milliseconds/seconds.

Comment: It depends - for repeatable executions bind variable might be faster. If there is a histogram on COLUMN1 then string literal might help optimizer to find better execution plan.

Comment: You don't have to use PL/SQL to have a bind variable, so you're including a context switch that might not be necessary, possibly obscuring your real concern. Depends where/how you're calling this too, and where your fixed value is coming from, and what you're doing with the result.